# Adding rows to collections not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

I'm trying to add a new row/value to the existing collection. But it shows the same older result after adding the row.

//Code

```
Using CustomActionWorkflow As New CustomActionWorkflow()
        CustomActionWorkflow.WorkflowId = Me.WorkflowId
        CustomActionWorkflow.CustomActionId = Me.CustomActionId
        Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection.ToList().Add(CustomActionWorkflow)
End Using
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the `CustomActionsWorkflowCollection` proeprty?

Comment: @nemesv: Its a collection of properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToList() function gives you the new copy of IEnumerable collection. You try to add to the list for which you have no reference.

Try if CustomActionsWorkflowCollection have Add method

```
Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection.Add(CustomActionWorkflow)
```

or if collection can be set

```
    var list = Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection.ToList(); 
list.Add(CustomActionWorkflow);
Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection = list;
```

But the last is not a good solution beacuse of creating a lot of temporary lists.

Comment: Do u want me to add without converting to list?

Comment: to give you a full answer we need to know the type of Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection

Comment: `Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection = Me.CustomActionsController.CustomActionsWorkflowCollection.ToList().Add(CustomActionWorkflow)` won't work since `List<T>.Add` has the return type `void`.